# EKF based Slam implementation with landmark identification in Global frame

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, ekf

I am working on mobile Robotics. I want to implement Slam. I have a very specific question about EKF Slam. To implement Slam I read the book "Probabilistic Robotics". I read its online version. There is a very well defined algorithm about EKF SLAM of known correspondence. But after read this algorithm again and again still fail to understand this algorithm, Especially where Landmarks portion is introduce. They are using range and bearing information to find out the landmarks (x,y) co-ordinates. This portion is little fishy for me. The value they get it is in Robot body Frame because the camera in attached with the Robot. So how could I get it Global Frame. I don't think there is any step in algorithm which transfer it to Global Frame. Any suggestion and discussion about this matter is most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which online version? (A link would help. There is also a "draft" version circulating). Which section of the text? (e.g. "section 10.3.1" with a page number). _Exactly_ which part of the explanation do you understand, and which part introduces the confusion.

Comment: Version that I don't know. But chapter 10 page No:261. Table No: 10.1. If you give me your mail id I can mail you this book which I have.